# Unable to use cargo build-sbf

Tags: solana-cli

When I run cargo build-sbf, the following error occurs

```
@LAPTOP-17NE3HC9 MINGW64 /d/CODE/Solana/hello_world (master)
$ cargo build-sbf
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`

        Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
        Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

This is my version of solana-cli 1.17.13 (src:ef1fb9ec; feat:4006346914, client:SolanaLabs)